# Clojure set vs distinct vs dedupe?

Tags: clojure

So if we want a collection of unique items we can use a 'set'.

If we already have a collection of items that we want to dedupe, we could pass them to the set function, or alternatively we could use the distinct or dedupe functions.

What are the situations for using each of these (pros/cons)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The differences are:

- [`set`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/set) will create a new set collection eagerly.
- [`distinct`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/distinct) will create a lazy sequence with duplicates from the input collection removed. It has an advantage over set if you process big collections and lazyness might save you from eagerly evaluating the input collection (e.g. with `take`)
- [`dedupe`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dedupe) removes **consecutive** duplicates from the input collection so it has a different semantics than `set` and `distinct`. For example it will return `(1 2 3 1 2 3)` when applied to `(1 1 1 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 3 3)`

Set and lazy seq have different APIs available (e.g. `disj`, `get` vs `nth`) and performance characteristics (e.g. O(log32 n) look up for set and O(n) for lazy seq) and they should be chosen depending on how you would like to use their results.

Additionally `distinct` and `dedupe` return a transducer when called without argument.

Comment: Maybe worth adding that `set` and `distinct` may render the collection in a different order. On my system, `(= ((comp seq set) (range 91)) (distinct (range 91))) => false`.

Comment: As a general rule, elements in a hash-set are only expected to be unique and NOT to be in any particular order, unlike a sorted-set which maintains order at all times but is limited to "comparable" elements.